# How to validate two properties with ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0

I'm just getting started with ASP.NET MVC 2, and playing around with Validation.

Let's say I have 2 properties:

- Password1
- Password2

And I want to require that they are both filled in, and require that both are the same before the model is valid.

I have a simple class called "NewUser".

How would I implement that? I've read about ValidationAttribute, and understand that. But I don't see how I would use that to implement a validation that compares two or more properties against eathother.

Thanks in advance!

***Problem with below solution***:

When this is applied to an application, and the ModelBinder runs the validation of the Model, then there **is** a problem:

If a **Property-level ValidationAttribute** contains an error, then the **Class-level ValidationAttribute**'s are ***NOT*** validated. I have not found a solution to this problem as of yet.

If you have a solution to this problem please share your experience. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default ASP.NET MVC 2 template of Visual Studio includes the exact validation attribute you need. Pasted from `AccountModels.cs` file :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, 
    AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class PropertiesMustMatchAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = 
        "'{0}' and '{1}' do not match.";
    private readonly object _typeId = new object();

    public PropertiesMustMatchAttribute(string originalProperty, 
        string confirmProperty)
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage) {
        OriginalProperty = originalProperty;
        ConfirmProperty = confirmProperty;
    }

    public string ConfirmProperty { get; private set; }
    public string OriginalProperty { get; private set; }

    public override object TypeId {
        get {
            return _typeId;
        }
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString,
            OriginalProperty, ConfirmProperty);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = 
           TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
        object originalValue = properties.Find(OriginalProperty, 
            true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
        object confirmValue = properties.Find(ConfirmProperty, 
            true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
        return Object.Equals(originalValue, confirmValue);
    }
}
```

How to use :

```
[PropertiesMustMatch("Password", "ConfirmPassword", 
    ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
class NewUser {
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Confirm password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The only problem I can see with this is, when two properties of the Model (class in this case), aren't equal, it doesn't denote the specific Properties as containing errors, like it does for [Required] and <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password1) %>

Comment: @CodeMonkey, I see. Though I'm not sure if there's an elegant solution to make it work the other way, using model binding. After all, this is technically a class-level validation. If you **must** add the errors to the properties instead, then maybe checking the two values in the controller after the binding would be the quickest solution (though not the most elegant).

Comment: In the MVC 2 version the Html.ValidationSummary helper method can now display Model-Level only errors