# MVC data annotation to compare one property to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I've been playing around data annotations in MVC2 and am curious if there is an annotation to compare 2 properties (ie. password, confirm password)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450198/how-to-validate-two-properties-with-asp-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go: http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/01/09/Property-Matching-With-Data-Annotations.aspx
**Edit:**
New link: http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/01/09/property-matching-with-data-annotations/

Answer (score 42):

If you are using ASP.Net MVC 3, you can use `System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute`

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("Password")]
public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
```

Comment: why is this in system.web.mvc instead of dataAnnotations? Shouldn't have to reference system.web.mvc in my model project. How annoying.

Comment: In .Net 4.5 it's in the System.Component.DataAnnotations as well.

Answer (score 2):

System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute has been deprecated.

I was able to modify to work like this:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not one built in, however, you can make your own.  See [this link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1499238/3588699.aspx#3588699), which shows the "PropertiesMustMatchAttribute" that does just what you're looking for.