# reference an MVC entity model in a custom validation attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

Using MVC4, say you had a custom validation entity model, is it possible to pass the model to a custom validation attribute, for example:

```
public class ValidatableModel
{
    [CustomValidation(typeof(CustomDependentValidation), "ValidateCDV", **this**)]
    public string Attrib1 { get; set; ]
    public string Attrib2 { get; set; }
}
```

to a CustomDependentValidation class declared like:

```
public class CustomDependentValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public static ValidationResult ValidateCDV(ValidatedModel argValMod) //yes, ?-able.
    { if (argValMod.Attrib1 == argValMod.Attrib2) { return ValidationResult.Success; } }
}
```

In the code above was an extrapodecrapulate attempt from the CustomValidation msdn page example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute(v=vs.95).aspx

(on the Silverlight version, I know... the other version pages didn't have any example code)

Is the self-referential validating model pattern-like-thing that I am trying to code just not possible in MVC4?

I guess it might be because Annotations don't permit object instance references or the entity model objects don't have any business being client side, but I am yet learning MVC and lose the business end of things easily.

Comment: note: I know there is already a simpler comparer annotation, this is just a simple example.  Being able to pass instance attributes would be just as good, but I figure would need an instance reference like "this.Attrib1"

Comment: ended up doing this validation server side, no annotations required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found some similar problem solution approaches on SO:

[Custom model validation of dependent properties using Data Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280539/custom-model-validation-of-dependent-properties-using-data-annotations)

[Property-level validation errors hinder the validation of Class-level validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099397/property-level-validation-errors-hinder-the-validation-of-class-level-validation)

short answer seems to be it is not possible.

answer sized answer is: this is not in the MVC4 box, but seems possible with enough work time

Answer (score 0):

In your custom Validation Attribute override the IsValid method as follows:

> protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)

validationContext contains the properties ObjectInstance and ObjectType. The first is your entity, the second the entity type.  That should provide you access to any other properties in the entity you need for validation (I think - just found it myself so I'll let you know if not..)